# Beginner probability question: How can I use indicator variables to solve this problem?

Tags: probability

This is from Sheldon Ross.

One of the numbers 1 through 10 is uniformly chosen at random. You have to guess the number chosen by asking “is it i?” for i = 1, . . . , 10.

Compute Q, the expected number of questions you will need to ask.

I get that the answer is 11/2.

**Method 1**

The pmf for Q is 1/10 for i = 1,...,10

So E[Q] = (1+2+...+10)/10 = 55/10 = 11/2

**Method 2**

Is there a way to solve this by breaking up Q into 10 indicator variables?

E[Q] = E[Q1 + Q2 + ... + Q10]

It seems to me the "indicator variables" will have to be:

E[Qi] = i with probability 1/10

But an indicator variable should be 1 or 0...

**Reason why I am asking**

I like how for the hyper geometric RV you can do E[X] = np where p is constant. But in Method 2 above the "p" in this case is not constant since it is i/10 for i = 1,...,10

Thank you!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of questions asked will be $$ Q = \sum_{i=1}^{10} Q_i$$ where $Q_i=1$ if the $i$-th question got asked and zero otherwise. Then you have $E(Q_i)$ is the probability the $i$-th question got asked which is the probability that the correct answer did not come before $i$ which is $$ E(Q_i) = \frac{11-i}{10}.$$ Then you have $$ E(Q) = \sum_{i=1}^{10} \frac{11-i}{10} = \sum_{k = 1}^{10} \frac{k}{10} = \frac{11}{2}.$$

As you alluded to, the indicator method is not as elegant here as in a lot of cases.

Comment: Crap you're right... my failure was in correctly thinking what E[Qi] would be as you defined it. Thank you for the explanation. This line you wrote really helped: "E[Qi] is the probability the i-th question got asked which is the probability that the correct answer did not come before i"

Comment: Yes $E(I_E) = P(E)$ for any event $E$ where $I_E$ is the indicator variable for the event. That's always true and very useful.